# Data Table from viewmodels list

Tags: session, model-view-controller, datatable, viewmodel

How can I convert a list of view models to data table to print it in PDF later?

i have an error in this line: `values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null).ToString();`
I can't convert it.

```
public ActionResult detailsoperation(OperationViewModel operationvm, 
         CategorieViewModel categories, string idd) {

     List<CategorieViewModel> list = (List<CategorieViewModel>)Session["categories"];
     list.Add(categories);
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(CategorieViewModel).Name);

     //Get all the properties
     PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(OperationViewModel)
             .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

     foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props) {
         //Setting column names as Property names
         dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
     }

     foreach (CategorieViewModel item in list) {
         var values = new object[Props.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++) {
             //inserting property values to datatable rows
             values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null).ToString();
         }
         dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
     }
```